# Mysql REGEXP how to do an exact match

Tags: mysql, regex

i have a notes column which contains text and has an id within the text, something like
"some random text (actvityid - 1234)"

i need to pull out the id 1234 in this case and update the activityid column within the same table.

my query looks like this

```
"UPDATE table_name SET activityId = {$f['activityId']} WHERE notes REGEXP '{$f['activityId']}' "
```

the problem with this is if $f['activityId'] is 34 or 123 for example it still updates the activityid column with that value. How can i do an exact match on "1234" and update only if it matches the whole string, here "1234".

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WHERE notes REGEXP CONCAT('(actvityid - ', {$f['activityId']}, ')')
```

or

```
WHERE notes REGEXP '[[:<:]]{$f['activityId']}[[:>:]]'
```

`[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` stands for [word boundaries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp).

Comment: hi well just to make it much clearer the notes column contains text something like this

"abc updated stage on project 13084 (Activity - 309)"

now i need to pull 309 out and update avtivityId coulmn within the same table.

Comment: @Naktibalda: the same problem using LIKE.

Comment: @Bharath You cannot read from a table in the same query as you're updating it, if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: no i am not trying to do that i am trying to do something like this

"UPDATE table_name SET activityId = {$f['activityId']} WHERE notes REGEXP '{$f['activityId']}' "

now consider notes to be "abc updated stage on project 13084 (Activity - 309)".

applying the above query assuming $f['activityId'] to be 30 the query will work and update activityId column with the value 30. which is exactly what my problem is. i need activityId column to be updated only if notes contained (Activity - 309) and $f['activityId'] = 309 as well. i am very sorry if i am not framing the question right.

Comment: @bharath If the `(activityid - ` part is guaranteed to be the same, why not use `like` as suggested in the other answer?

Comment: yeah true but what if the notes had (activityid - 309) and $f['activityId'] = 30. LIKE will still match it won't it?

i want it match only if notes had (activityid - 309) and $f['activityId'] = 309.

Comment: @bharath did you try my examples? because both of them takes that into account - what did you get?

Comment: hi there you guys were right it was my fault....i've been doin a very silly mistake all along....sorry about that....and thanks a lot for your time, you've been a great help :)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use CONCAT if variable is passed from PHP,
and no need to use REGEXP if you match exact string without special characters

```
WHERE notes LIKE '%(actvityid - {$f['activityId']})%'
```